# How to access viewbag value in AJAX success?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Here I `EditMyProfile` method which is used to edit the customer detail. 
In this method I am trying to set `ViewBag.msg = 1` and return `return PartialView("MyProfile", getCusomerDetail);`, set `ViewBag.msg = 0;` and return `return PartialView("EditMyProfile", customer);` and using that `ViewBag.msg` value want put condition on AJAX success whether to show success message or not.

Now, the problem is that even though the `ViewBag.msg` has value in `EditMyProfile` view, the `var message = '@ViewBag.msg'` gives `var message = ""` in AJAX success.
Any help with my code will be a great help
Thank you

Below is my AJAX

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#EditMyProfileCreate").submit(function (ev) {
        debugger;
        ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var Action = $(this).attr('action');
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: Action,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                debugger
                var message = '@ViewBag.msg'; // Here the var message = "" even though @ViewBag.msg' has value
                if (message == "1") {
                    swal("Congratulations!", "Chages saved successfully", "success");
                    $("section#myAccountMainDiv").html(data);
                }
                else {
                    $("section#myAccountMainDiv").html(data);
                }                   
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

Below is my

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditMyProfile(CustomerVM customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (emedicineEntities _db = new emedicineEntities())
            {
                var getCustomer = _db.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();
                getCustomer.CustomerName = customer.CustomerName;
                getCustomer.CustomerPhoneNumber = customer.CustomerPhoneNumber;
                getCustomer.CustomerEmail = customer.CustomerEmail;
                getCustomer.CustomerAddress = customer.CustomerAddress;
                getCustomer.ConfirmPassword = getCustomer.PasswordHash;                   
                _db.Entry(getCustomer).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _db.SaveChanges();

                ViewBag.msg = 1; // here ViewBag.msg is set 1 on successfull edit 

                var getId = Global.CustomerId;
                var getCusomerDetail = _db.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerId == getId).FirstOrDefault();
                return PartialView("MyProfile", getCusomerDetail);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.msg = 0; // here ViewBag.msg is set 0 when model is invalid 

            return PartialView("EditMyProfile", customer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Am I wrong if I say that once the view is rendered, the model objects cease to exist? This one thing about the Razor view engine is still a bit confusing for me

Answer (score 0):

To Access ViewBag dictionary in javascript, your Javascript code block must be on the cshtml file and not in the external javascript file.

In Controlller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Data = "haha";
        return View();
    }
```

In cshtml file

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {                   
            alert('@ViewBag.Data');
        });
    </script>
```

As you are calling your controller through an Ajax call, you need to return the data as a variable inside your partial view. What i would suggest is to create a hidden field inside your partial view's cshtml file and assign that the value of ViewBag property at compile time. Then inside success function get the value of hidden field and compare.